# Ways of setting up a Random Forrest in Python

Tags: python, random-forest, decision-tree

What is the differences (advantages, disadvantages) between the following 3 methods? Specifically, what does the bagging classifier, max_features = 1., do? Because setting it to a float lower than 1 results in an error but it should include the randomness in the trees. However, maybe this is done in the base estimators max_features parameter? Is so, what does the bagging classifiers max_features parameter do?

```
# model 1
clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion='entropy', max_features="auto",
                             class_weight='balanced', min_weight_fraction_leaf=minWLeaf)
clf = BaggingClassifier(base_estimator=clf, n_estimators=n_estimators,
                        max_features=1., max_samples=max_samples,
                        oob_score=True, n_jobs=n_jobs)
# model 2
clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=n_estimators, class_weight='balanced_subsample', criterion='entropy')
# model 3
clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=1, class_weight='balanced_subsample', 
                             criterion='entropy', bootstrap=False, oob_score=True)
clf = BaggingClassifier(base_estimator=clf, n_estimators=n_estimators,
                        max_features=1., max_samples=max_samples,
                        oob_score=True, n_jobs=n_jobs)
```

Comment: which tech are you using ? Python and ? please tag.

Comment: max_features = 1 means the amount of independent variables you will use. At least one variable must be used. You cannot use 0.34 variables as a feature.

Comment: Can anyone else explain if these implementation are exactly alike, ie. are they all a random forest? Of course, model 2 is but model 1 and 3 seems to me to being just bagged trees with no "random" subselection of features.